# Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create an insert form where the user can insert the details of a new product (sweet) into a MYSQL database.

The product image is inserted into the specified directory `item_images/$product_image`.

However, that item is not inserted into the database and following error is produced:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: 
Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /home/k1335948/www/loginregister-master/insert_product.php:168 
Stack trace: #0 /home/k1335948/www/loginregister-master/insert_product.php(168): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} 
thrown in /home/k1335948/www/loginregister-master/insert_product.php on line 168
```

Database connection is fine as my other statements work for other elements.

I don't have much experience with PDO and I have been looking for solutions both here and online.

```
if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])) {

    $product_title = $_POST['title'];
    $product_cat = $_POST['item_cat'];
    $product_brand = $_POST['item_brand'];
    $product_price = $_POST['price'];
    $product_desc = $_POST['description'];
    $product_keywords = $_POST['keyword'];

    // retrieving image 
    $product_image  = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
    $product_image_tmp  = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"item_images/$product_image");

    $insert_product = "INSERT INTO items(photo, title, description, keyword, price, item_category, item_brand) VALUES (:product_image, :product_title, :product_desc, :product_keywords, :product_price, :product_cat, :product_brand)";

    $insert_pro = $db->prepare($insert_product); 
    $results = $insert_pro->execute(array(
    ":product_image" => $product_image,
    ":title" => $product_title,
    ":product_desc" => $product_desc,
    ":product_keywords" => $product_keywords,
    ":product_price" => $product_price,
    ":product_cat" => $product_cat,
    ":product_brand" => $product_brand));

    if($insert_pro){

    echo "<script>alert('Product has been added sucessfully')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('insert_product.php','_self')</script>";
    }
}
```

(Edited) Here is my form:

```
    <form action ="insert_product.php" name="insert_form" method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">

    <table align="center" width="100%" border="2" bgcolor="pink">

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Title: </b></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="product_title" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Category: </b></td>
        <td>
        <select name="product_cat" />
        <option>Select Category: <option>

        <?php getCat(); ?>

        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Brand: </b></td>
        <td>
        <select name="product_brand" />
        <option>Choose Brand: <option>

        <?php getBrand(); ?>

        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Image: </b></td>
        <td>
        <input type="file" name="product_image" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Price: </b></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="product_price" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Description: </b></td>
        <td>
        <textarea name="product_desc" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Keywords: </b></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="product_keywords" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="8"><input type="submit" name="insert_post" value="Insert New Product" /></td>
    </tr>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in preparing the SQL or at least on the `execute` function. You don't bind all the requested values to the defined params in your SQL string.

Specifically the `:product_title` in the SQL and `:title` in your execute `method`.

```
$insert_pro->execute(array(
  ":product_image" => $product_image,
  ":product_title" => $product_title,
  ":product_desc" => $product_desc,
  ":product_keywords" => $product_keywords,
  ":product_price" => $product_price,
  ":product_cat" => $product_cat,
  ":product_brand" => $product_brand
));
```

And it should be:

```
if($results){
  // product has been successfully added.
}
```

Comment: I've made the changes to the code where specified, however i'm receiving this new error now: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: Perhaps you're using an older version of PHP. Change `[arraydata]` to `array(arraydata)`

Comment: This is the version i'm using: Current PHP version: 5.2.5. I've also made the changes but the error is still there.

Comment: The only thing you need to do is change `:title` to `:product_title` but I've updated my code for you now too.

Comment: your new suggested code has removed the "parse error", however there is a new error similar to the first one: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null' in /home/k1335948/www/loginregister-master/insert_product.php:169 Stack trace: #0 /home/k1335948/www/loginregister-master/insert_product.php(169): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/k1335948/www/loginregister-master/insert_product.php on line 169

Comment: That means `$_POST['title']` is not submitting correctly through the form, check the name attribute of the title input?

Comment: I adjusted the constraint for the 'title' column to accept null values, but now i am receiving the same error message for the description column which means that none of the '$_POST''s are submitting correctly. Any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

My form names were not matching the names in my database table -items-. All I needed to do was adjust the names to match the ones in the -items- table. Crazy errors but simple solution. :) Thanks for the help anyway @Xorifelse.

Comment: I really don't understand this, **html form names** not matching the **column names in the database**? These two languages don't even communicate with each other. The correct issue is that `$_POST['title']` is null because your HTML form input uses a different name `name="product_title"` so `$_POST['product_title']` would have been the solution.